# Is there any way to invoke onsumit event after @sumit.prevent done in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have VUEJS's form as:

```
<form @submit.prevent="commonPanelEntryRestore" method="post" action="url" onsubmit="heightGraph()">

</form>
```

I want to call `heightGraph()` function after vuejs `@submit` event completed.

Is it possible in Vuejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use finally method from Axios library.

```js
 export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        methods: {
            commonPanelEntryRestore() {
                axios.post(url, data).then(response => {
                    // success
                }).catch(error => {
                    // error
                }).finally(function() {
                    this.heightGraph()
                })
            },
            heightGraph() {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its ok you just call your function on finally

Comment: Is there any way to call it in form?

Comment: I did it another way

Answer (score 1):

As per my requirement, this solution has worked,

```
<form @submit.prevent="commonPanelEntryRestore" method="post" action="url" onsubmit="heightGraph()">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="reset_height_sagraph" style="display: none;" onclick="heightGraph()"></a>
</form>
```

In the vue js method:

```
setTimeout(function(){              
    document.getElementById("reset_height_sagraph").click();
 },800);
```

This is working for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    commonPanelEntryRestore() {
      // some logic before
      heightGraph()
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: it gives errors undefine function call while gulp run.

Comment: @GufranHasan, do you have that function in the global scope?

Comment: Yes it is in global scope